# Mongo replication performance issue when retrieving document from replica set

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongodb-replica-set

I have one primary and two secondary replica sets and there is a performance issue when I retrieve document from my node server. So is there a way to increase the performance?

Comment: what performance issue ??

Answer (score 0):

See, directly there is no direct effect on performance due to replication. But it gives certain effects like slow, lagging, etc on read/write operations due to the hit on storage of oplogs.

So if you want to enhance the performance, just increase the size of storage.

Comment: I resolved this issue, one of the replica set(secondary) is not reachable and that slows down any operations read/write. I removed the unreachable node and now it works fine. Is my understanding right?